# How to pass php variable to JavaScript function as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass php image url as javascript function parameter.

Please let me know how can I do this.

```html
<html> 
<?php
$image=$row['image'];
$img=$loc.'user/'.$image;
?>

<script type=text/javascript>
function demo()
{
some code here;
}
   </script>

<body>
<button type="submit" onclick=demo(<?php echo $img?>) >
</body>
</html>
```

In javascript I am doing some editing work on image .

How can I pass this php variable (i.e. image url as javascript function parameter)

Comment: after wrapping, you havr to close the button as well. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the PHP code within `quotes` like as

```
<button type="submit" onclick="demo('<?php echo $imageurl;?>');" >
                                  //^^                      ^^
```

Within your Javascript as you were passing value within function but not capturing that value within your `function demo()`

```
function demo(obj)
{           //^^^ Capturing value within function using variable name obj
   alert(obj);
}
```

Comment: sir, I  tried this solution also. but still not passing value in javascript function

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap it with quotes and you have to close the `button`

```
<button type="submit" onclick='demo("<?php echo $imageurl?>")' ></button>
```

Comment: @Saty question is edited by OP, see this, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33521183/revisions

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="demo('<?php echo $img;?>');" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `$img` is your variable and in code you are trying to send `$imageurl`

```
<html> 
<?php
$image=$row['image'];
$img=$loc.'user/'.$image;
?>

<script>
function demo(val1)
{
      alert(val1);
}
</script>
<body>
<button type="submit" onclick=demo('<?php echo $img?>') >Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```