# Passing PHP values to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this value getting in my php:

```
  <?php echo $city_name; ?>
```

I have a doubt passing this value to the jquery. I need to append this $cityname with the popular_hotels1.php. i need to append it here:

```
$("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?city_name=city_name&page=1", Hide_Load());
```

My complete jquery is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

//Display Loading Image
function Display_Load()
{
    $("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
    $("#loading").html("<img src='bigLoader.gif' />");
}
//Hide Loading Image
function Hide_Load()
{
    $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
};

 //Default Starting Page Results

$("#pagination li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'none'});

Display_Load();

$("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?page=1", Hide_Load());
//Pagination Click
$("#pagination li").click(function(){

    Display_Load();

    //Loading Data
    var pageNum = this.id;

    $("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
});

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass php variable to JavaScript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521183/how-to-pass-php-variable-to-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: var city_name = "<?php echo $city_name; ?>"; Doing this php variable will be accessible in the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass php variable's value to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946829/how-to-pass-php-variables-value-to-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the php variable in a jquery variable as following:

`var cityName = <?php echo $city_name; ?>`

in your code:

```
$("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?city_name=" + cityName + "&page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
```

Comment: I have a doubt. Is this the correct syntax?   $("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?city_name="+ cityName + "page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());

Answer (score 0):

Put your jquery code in php file after That you can directly use it like.

```
$("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?city_name= <?php echo $city_name; ?>&page=1", Hide_Load());
```

Comment: Is this correct?         $("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?page=" + pageNum&city_name= <?php echo $city_name; ?>, Hide_Load());

Comment: Because there are two places which i need to add city_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the php code in a span tag having an id, then use the same id to call in jQuery code.

PHP Code:

```
<span id="demo"><?php echo $city_name; ?></span>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var data = $("#demo").html();

$("#content").load("popular_hotels1.php?city_name=" +data + "&page="+pageNum, Hide_Load());
```

Comment: I need to pass the $city_name value to another php query. Is it possible?